# no configuration file provided: not found for docker compose up --scale chrome=5

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-selenium

This might look similar to this [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256928/docker-compose-prompted-error-no-configuration-file-provided-not-found) but I have tried all the solutions mentioned there and none seems to resolve my issue.
I have created a docker compose file , [Docker-Compose-V3.yml](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml).

On running `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml up` I am able to successfully spin up the grid network.

When I am trying to scale my chrome nodes using `docker-compose up --scale chrome = 5` I am getting `no configuration file provided: not found` error message

I have tried following solutions from the existing answer linked but to no avail

1. Made sure I am in correct directory where the docker compose file is present
2. Checked the extension of yml file and cross checked the folder option settings

I am unable to understand that why is docker able to identify the compose file when asked to spin  up the grid but fails to do so when I am trying to scale up the services.
I know that another possible way I can do it is using docker swarm which I came to know of while scrolling through docker documentation but would like to understand why this isn't working.

Needless to say but I have just started exploring the docker world and would appreciate any help in being pointed towards the existing documentation/answers that would resolve my problem

Comment: In the command you mentioned to scale "chrome", try adding `-f docker-compose-v3.yml`

Comment: Tried doing this as well with following command docker-compose up --scale chrome=5 -f docker-compose-v3.yaml , errors out unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f

Comment: The command should be "docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml up --scale chrome=5"

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have started 'docker-compose up' from the wrong path where you currently located. Try to open the folder with your project and start the command after that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).