# Docker compose ubuntu 22.04 error no configuration file provided: not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my ubuntu 22.04 with a docker compose version v2.17.2, when I try to execute the command docker compose up I receive this error:

```
XXXX@ubuntu:/develop/composetest$ docker compose up
no configuration file provided: not found
```

I'm in a folder with a compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

If can help, I try whith this command:

```
docker compose -f compose.yaml up
```

And result is:

```
stat /var/lib/snapd/void/compose.yaml: no such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose prompted error: no configuration file provided: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256928/docker-compose-prompted-error-no-configuration-file-provided-not-found)

Comment: No, if you read better the answer the problem is related to the docker compose up commands, and not for the docker compose logs ...

Comment: What files are in `/develop/composetest`?

Comment: This is the exercise of official guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/: app.py  compose.yaml   Dockerfile  requirements.txt

Comment: I've seen some similar odd issues go by related to the Ubuntu "Snap" packaging system, and the path name suggests you might be running into this.  Might it help to uninstall Docker/Compose and reinstall it with the Debian APT package manager?

Answer (score -1):

The default name of configuration yaml for docker compose is `docker-compose.yml`. You can rename `compose.yaml` to `docker-compose.yml` and run `docker compose up` directly.

If you want to use another file name:

- Use `.yml` instead of `.yaml`
- Add relative path to command: `docker compose -f ./compose.yml up`

Comment: _compose.yaml_ is also looked at per default: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_file